# Iterative download using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

## **My Issue:**

I am attempting to download all files located here (https://mft.rrc.texas.gov/link/1bf41875-3edd-4660-8ec5-b4cd15880563) using Java/HtmlUnit. (Each 'download' is a returned as a .zip containing selected files)

I have been able to download multiple files by checking the individual boxes on the left and then clicking on 'Download' at the bottom of the page with out issue.

However, I am unable to download the files from the first page *and then* click on the 'next page' button at the bottom - such that I may download files not displayed on the initial page.

## **What I've Tried:**

I have tried several variations of this, and have not been able to download anything from the second page. Any time I download a file, the following navigation step takes me back to the first page.

Said another way, I am able to navigate through any number of pages one by one, but if at any point I attempt the download, the next page I hit is identical to the first.

Some example code below.

**Note(1):** I am calling navigateTable(...) which is calling downloadAll(...). I have tried doing this in a single code block as well but end up with the same results.

**Note(2):** 'Page' may not be the most appropriate term here as the 'next' anchor just loads new content into a webtable at the same url.

## **Code:**

```
    public static synchronized void downloadAll(WebClient wc, HtmlPage page, String downloadpath, String downloadname) throws Exception {

        HtmlPage queue) = (HtmlPage)wc.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();

        wc.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        
        //find and click checkbox indicating download all files on page
        HtmlCheckBoxInput queuebox = (HtmlCheckBoxInput)queue.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"fileTable:j_id_1s\"]/div/div[1]/input").get(0);
        queue = (HtmlPage)queuebox.setChecked(true);
        wc.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        
        //print element showing how many rows are selected
        String numselected = queue.getElementById("totalRows").asNormalizedText();
        System.out.println(numselected);
        
        //find and click download button (should download all rows checked as a single zip file)
        System.out.println("Downloading file...");
        HtmlButton downloadbutton = (HtmlButton)queue.getHtmlElementById("j_id_3c:j_id_3c");
        System.out.println(downloadbutton.asNormalizedText());
        System.out.println("Clicking Download...");
        downloadbutton.click();
        System.out.println("Waiting for js...");
        wc.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        Page downloadpage = wc.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage(); 
        
        //save download to disk
        File destfile = new File(downloadpath, downloadname);                                                            
        try (InputStream contentAsStream = downloadpage.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream()) {                   
            try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destfile)) {                                              
                IOUtils.copy(contentAsStream, out);                                                                
            }                                                                                                      
        }
        System.out.println("File downloaded to:" + destfile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    
    
    public static synchronized void navigateTable(String url, int npages, String downloadpath, String downloadname, String downloadext) throws Exception {
        //suppress logs
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
        
        //create webclient
        WebClient wc = new WebClient(); //BrowserVersion.CHROME
        wc.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wc.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
        wc.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        wc.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        
        //get initial page
        HtmlPage queue = wc.getPage(url);
        
        //do n times
        for (int i = 1; i < npages+1; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Current Iteration: %d", i));
            
            //print 'showing' status from page
            HtmlElement showing = (HtmlElement)queue.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"fileTable_paginator_bottom\"]/span[1]").get(0);
            System.out.println(showing.asNormalizedText());
            
            //call download
            downloadAll(wc, queue, downloadpath, String.format("%s_%d.%s", downloadname, i, downloadext));
            
            //get 'next page' button and click it, resetting current page to be next page
            System.out.println("Navigating to next queue page...");
            HtmlAnchor nextpageanchor = (HtmlAnchor)queue.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"fileTable_paginator_bottom\"]/a[3]").get(0);
            queue = (HtmlPage)nextpageanchor.click();
            
            //wait a sec for page to load
            wc.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);
            System.out.println("Arrived at next queue page...");
        }
        
        //close webclient
        wc.close();
    }
```

## **Console output:**

```
Current Iteration: 1
Showing 1 - 250 of 15544
250 Rows Selected
Downloading file...
Download
Clicking Download...
Waiting for js...
File downloaded to:C:\Drilling Permits Pending Approval_2023-01-04_204350_1.zip
Navigating to next queue page...
Arrived at next queue page...
Current Iteration: 2
Showing 1 - 250 of 15544
250 Rows Selected
Downloading file...
Download
Clicking Download...
Waiting for js...
File downloaded to:C:\Drilling Permits Pending Approval_2023-01-04_204350_2.zip
Navigating to next queue page...
Arrived at next queue page...
Current Iteration: 3
Showing 1 - 250 of 15544
250 Rows Selected
Downloading file...
Download
Clicking Download...
Waiting for js...
File downloaded to:C:\Drilling Permits Pending Approval_2023-01-04_204350_3.zip
Navigating to next queue page...
Arrived at next queue page...
```

## **Console output with downloadAll(...) line commented out:**

```
Current Iteration: 1
Showing 1 - 250 of 15544
Navigating to next queue page...
Arrived at next queue page...
Current Iteration: 2
Showing 251 - 500 of 15544
Navigating to next queue page...
Arrived at next queue page...
Current Iteration: 3
Showing 501 - 750 of 15544
Navigating to next queue page...
Arrived at next queue page...
```

## **Final Thoughts:**

Again, my problem is not navigating, or the downloading of files specifically.. But, how to do both at the same time.

Notice that without the download portion the table is updated as expected (illustrated by the *Showing ### - ### of 15544* line of the console output)

What is going on here?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess...

HtmlUnit is a bit different from what you expect from your browser in handling downloads. Maybe for your case it is helpful to implement your own AttachmentHanlder (https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/filedownload-howto.html).

I think you have to implement

```
boolean handleAttachment(final WebResponse response)
```

in a way this method saves the Attachment and also returns true. This will avoid the replacement of the page in the current window with the downloaded content. And in the end you have still the table in your window and further navigation should work.

If not please open an issue on github and i will try to have a closer look.

Comment: Thank you @RBRi, I will give this a try and let you know how it works out.